# ROS on Raspberry Pi Model 2: UbuntuARM vs ROSBerryPi

Tags: ros, raspberry-pi, arm-cpu

Before I ask my question, I'd better confirm that I've read the most prominent post about [running ROS on Raspberry Pi devices](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/230/can-ros-run-on-a-raspberry-pi/7844#7844).

That post contains some valuable information, but it's a bit dated, and ROS support for ARM devices is much better these days. In fact, ROS 2.0 is evidently going to have excellent support for [running on embedded devices](http://design.ros2.org/articles/why_ros2.html#new-use-cases) like the Raspberry Pi.

I just got a Pi model 2 for my birthday, and I'm really eager to get ROS running on it so I can build a robot I've been working on, which is based on the Wild Thumper 6WD platform.

From my perspective, here are a few pros & cons regarding UbuntuARM and ROSBerryPi:

UbuntuARM

**Pros:**

- Ubuntu is the official ROS distro and is the most well-supported ROS OS
- The best documentation on the ROS wiki for running on ARM devices is written for UbuntuARM

**Cons:**

- Raspbian (on which ROSBerryPi is based) is the official distro for Rasbperry Pi and thus has the best support for the board.

---

ROSBerryPi

**Pros:**

- Raspbian (on which ROSBerryPi is based) is the official distro for Rasbperry Pi and thus has the best support for the board.
  **Cons:**
- ROS is not well supported on OS's other than Ubuntu
- To use the ROSBerryPi distro, you must build ROS from source.

My question is: can anyone provide any further insight into this dilemma? If you've been running ROS on your Raspberry Pi 2 (model 2 only please; the model B+ has completely different issues, like not being well-supported by Ubuntu), what's your experience been?

Which distro would/did you choose, and why?

Answer (score 6):

The ROSBerryPi page is quite outdated, you actually can [install prebuilt ROS Groovy binaries on Raspbian](http://wiki.ros.org/groovy/Installation/Raspbian).

You will be better off installing prebuilt ROS binaries rather than building from source on your pi.

I don't have any experience with Ubuntu on the raspi but it's running great on my Odroid UX4 (similar single board computer) and ROS Jade runs just fine on that. See [these instructions](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/UbuntuARM) for how to install Ubuntu on your pi. Running Ubuntu will allow you to easily use the latest ROS distribution and packages.

Comment: I second this. Once you get Ubuntu onto your RasPi2, you can use pre-built ROS binaries. I would suggest trying Jade first, then Indigo, then Groovy. But once you have a ROS build that works for you, it should function mostly fine. Just double check any packages you use, and make sure they can execute on ARM architectures.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bit late (and slightly opinionated), but I have found [Ubuntu Mate](https://ubuntu-mate.org/) a very effective operating system to run ROS on a RasPi. It can access the arm repos for ROS and it is Ubuntu, so it brings the best of both worlds. Ubuntu Mate is supported and can run pre-built binaries for kinetic and melodic without a hitch (I have done this).